# too much margin for my figure

Tags: margins

I am receiving too much margin for this figure. The figure appear in one full page and I tried \vspace*{-5pt}. Nothing changed. Will be grateful if you help.

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}   
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}          
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[scaled=2]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning,fit, calc, patterns}
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}   
\newcommand{\minim}{\mathop{\hbox{min}}}
\newcommand{\minimize}[1]{\displaystyle\minim_{#1}}
\newcommand{\st}{\mathop{\hbox{s.t: \thinspace}}} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize 
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:4cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\fourthcircle{(-1.8cm:0.9cm) circle (0.5cm)}
\def\fifthcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\sixthcircle{(0:4.5cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=white, draw=circle edge, thick},
outline/.style={draw=black, thick}}

\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
\draw (n1) -- (n2);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\draw (n2) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n4) -- (n5);
\draw (n5) -- (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Graph $G$ as an (isolated) system}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {1};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {2};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {5};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {4};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {3};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
\draw (n1) -- (n2);
\draw (n2) -- (n3);
\draw (n2) -- (n4);
\draw (n2) -- (n5);
\draw (n3) -- (n4);
\draw (n4) -- (n5);
\draw (n5) -- (n1);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) -- (n8);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n9);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n10);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=10,in=10] (n9);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=-198,in=190,looseness=2] (n10);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=-30,in=30,looseness=4] (n9);
\draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=100,in=200,looseness=3.5] (n10);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Graph $G^\star=(N^\star,A^\star)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you edit your post so that it provides code which we can copy, paste and compile to reproduce the problem? And could you explain what you mean by it has 'too much margin'? Unless you've changed the margins for the current page or part of your document, the margins are presumably what they usually are.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited. Two figures are coded: one with regular margins; the second one with two much margins in all directions.

Comment: The M in MWE stands for minimal.

Comment: We'd like both minimal and working, if possible, actually. So `\end{document}` should be there somewhere.

Comment: Off-topic: `hyperref` needs to be loaded last with the exception of certain special packages, most notably `cleveref`. It won't work properly if loaded first.

Comment: Don't use `aeguill`. There are much better options than `ae` now. And these will not work well with `helvet` and `courier`. (Neither will their modern replacements, though.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. What is your preferred replacement for aeguill?

Comment: None. You don't need it anymore since you load `T1` fontencoding. Also, nowadays you should use `utf8` input encoding, which all systems and all modern editors understand.

Comment: I have no  problem with your code. I just added  `centering` right  after `begin{figure}`.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. The problem is that Figure 2 occupies one whole page. I think it's unnecessary. Because there are a lot of empty space on top and bottom of the figure. I hope there is a way to remove part of that empty space such that the figure only occupies half a page.

Comment: unrelated but `\newcommand{\minimize}[1]{\displaystyle\minim_{#1}}` will put the entire expression following that into display style, is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat trimmed document, with `\fbox`es to show why your figures are placed as they are.

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% these will look horrible with CM or CM-like fonts
% \usepackage[scaled=2]{helvet}
% \usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}% don't load packages twice
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning,fit, calc, patterns}% shapes and arrows are deprecated
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, nohead]{geometry}% so fancyhdr is only for footers? no headers in this document?
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize % this is a terrible idea - at least use setspace, but this is too little anyway
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}
\newcommand{\minim}{\mathop{\hbox{min}}}
\newcommand{\minimize}[1]{\displaystyle\minim_{#1}}
\newcommand{\st}{\mathop{\hbox{s.t: \thinspace}}}
\newcommand*\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\newcommand*\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\newcommand*\thirdcircle{(0:4cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\newcommand*\fourthcircle{(-1.8cm:0.9cm) circle (0.5cm)}
\newcommand*\fifthcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\newcommand*\sixthcircle{(0:4.5cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=white, draw=circle edge, thick},
outline/.style={draw=black, thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
        \draw (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);
        \draw (n2) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n4) -- (n5);
        \draw (n5) -- (n1);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G$ as an (isolated) system}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {1};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {2};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {5};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {4};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {3};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
        \draw (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);
        \draw (n2) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n4) -- (n5);
        \draw (n5) -- (n1);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) -- (n8);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n10);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=10,in=10] (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=-198,in=190,looseness=2] (n10);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=-30,in=30,looseness=4] (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=100,in=200,looseness=3.5] (n10);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G^\star=(N^\star,A^\star)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: figures in boxes]

The second figure is simply too big for LaTeX to place it at the top or bottom (or 'here'), given its algorithm for float placement. So, it moves it to a float page and, since it is the only float to end up there, it is on a page of its own.

The margins are untouched. This is just how floats work.

A more minimal version:

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, nohead]{geometry}% so fancyhdr is only for footers? no headers in this document?
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
        \draw (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);
        \draw (n2) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n4) -- (n5);
        \draw (n5) -- (n1);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G$ as an (isolated) system}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {1};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {2};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {5};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {4};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {3};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
        \draw (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n2) -- (n4);
        \draw (n2) -- (n5);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        \draw (n4) -- (n5);
        \draw (n5) -- (n1);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) -- (n8);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n10);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=10,in=10] (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=-198,in=190,looseness=2] (n10);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=-30,in=30,looseness=4] (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=100,in=200,looseness=3.5] (n10);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G^\star=(N^\star,A^\star)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces essentially the same output.

If you wish to change the image's bounding box, then there are various ways to do it. Probably the easiest in this case is to tell PGF not to count the curves and then add a few extra coordinates to expand the bounding box later.

For example,

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, nohead]{geometry}% so fancyhdr is only for footers? no headers in this document?
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
      \draw (n1) -- (n2);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
      \draw (n2) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n4) -- (n5);
      \draw (n5) -- (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G$ as an (isolated) system}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{% this method is considered evil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n1) at (1,10) {1};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n2) at (5,10)  {2};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n5) at (1,6)  {5};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n4) at (5,6) {4};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=black]  (n3) at (10,8)  {3};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n7) at (2,8.5) {$F_1$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n8) at (3.5,7) {$F_2$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n9) at (7,8) {$F_3$};
      \node[shape=circle,draw=red,thick]  (n10) at (3.5,4.5) {$F_4$};
      \draw (n1) -- (n2);
      \draw (n2) -- (n3);
      \draw (n2) -- (n4);
      \draw (n2) -- (n5);
      \draw (n3) -- (n4);
      \draw (n4) -- (n5);
      \draw (n5) -- (n1);
      \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) -- (n8);
      \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n9);
      \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n8) -- (n10);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=10,in=10] (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=-198,in=190,looseness=2]coordinate [pos=.5] (c3) (n10);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n10) to [out=-30,in=30,looseness=4] coordinate [pos=.2] (c1)  coordinate [pos=.7] (c2)  (n9);
        \draw[draw=red, dashed, thick] (n7) to [out=100,in=200,looseness=3.5] coordinate [pos=.2] (c4) (n10);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \path (c1) (c2) (c3) (c4);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  \caption{Graph $G^\star=(N^\star,A^\star)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: images with an adjusted bounding box for the second]

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot for the wonderful help :)